# Mysql Delete function not working, given correct URL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a function in which, when a button is pressed, PHP deletes that record from within the database. The website is being redirected with the correct ID, and the DeleteID Variable has the correct value in it, yet for some reason I can't get it to delete the record

**Delete.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();

//get value of ?id= from the url
$DeleteID = $_GET['id'];

echo $DeleteID;
require("connect.php");

//Linking
$link = connectToDB();

//SQL Query
$sql = "DELETE
          FROM tbl_property
          WHERE propetyid = $DeleteID";

//Execute
$result = $link->query($sql);

//Check
if ($link->affected_rows == 1) {
    echo "Worked";
    echo "<a href='properties.php'> SIGH </a>";
}
else {
    echo "Didn't Work";
    echo "<a href='properties.php'> SIGH </a>";
}
?>
```

**Table**

[image]

Comment: typo. There's typo in `propetyid = $DeleteID"`. Use `propertyid` instead

Comment: **STOP!!** Absolutely never use `$_GET` requests for modifications, *especially* not deletions. [It never ends well](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/08/08/hey-you-deleted-my-files/)

Comment: You should also be aware that your code is open to SQL injection, and really should be looked into.

Comment: `delete.php?id=0%20OR%201%3D1` wheee :D

Comment: had you been checking for (the real) error, you'd of been thrown something about it. Typo questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in field name you type `propetyid` instead of `propertyid`

```
$sql = "DELETE
          FROM tbl_property
          WHERE propetyid = $DeleteID";
```